# creating table with correct data

Tags: sql, oracle

Im having problems finding the correct data. I have a Table which contains customers(customerID). Each customer is connected to a certain phonenumber(PhoneNr). Every number starts with 2-9. 
Every customer have a callcenter(CallCenterID) they can call iff needed. 
I want to know how many customers call each callcenter, divided from 2-9(PhoneNumber).
So I want to know how many calls a callcenter gets from every customer with 5, as there starting number in phonenumber.

So far so good. My Code in sql:

```
Select CallCenter, Count(Customers) AS Number
from ******
Where PhoneNumber Like '45%' --Just need the numbers from Danish customers.
Group By Callcenter;
```

Im new to much of this, but i've tried the whole day to come up with the right result.
Right now Im getting every callcenter, and the number for every call to them. 
Can anyone help me?
:)

Comment: is this only 1 table?

Comment: I can see that my "explaining" lacks a bit in the names of the callcenter and the phonenumber.

Comment: is there a reason Count(*) didn't work? Would return all the callcenters with a Phone number Like 45% and the number of rows associated with it (assuming each customer has its own row)

Comment: I dont know how to explain it correct, but i want to get the following in af new table:

Comment: digit(2-9), number(of customers), callcenter..

example: 4, 454352, Copenhagen CallCenter..

So 454352 customers, have been calling Copenhagen Callcenter, with a phonenumber that starts with 4.

Comment: Do you want to only want to return rows for a specific digit (4 in your example), or do you want rows for all digits - one row per digit for each call center?

Comment: I want rows for all digits(2-9). But at the same time, all the digits can "call" every callcenter, so I figure that there may be about 8(2-9) rows per callcenter

Comment: Then my answer should work for you.  It returns a callcenter, the digit the phonenumber starts with, and the count for that digit at that callcenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the counts for all CallCenter's broken down by the first digit in the PhoneNumber:

```
SELECT CallCenter, SUBSTR(PhoneNumber, 1, 1) as startsWith, COUNT(*) as number
FROM myTable
GROUP BY CallCenter, SUBSTR(PhoneNumber, 1, 1)
ORDER BY 2, 3
```

If that's not what you wanted, please explain your question a bit better.